# Deezer Player incompatibility with arm architecture

Tags: ios, xcode, deezer

using the API in Xcode i must compile the project avoiding the 64 bit arc, but while I'm trying to use the DeezerAudioPlayer I get a incompatibility problem with the armv7 arc.

How I should compile the project in order to avoid all architecture problems?

REPORT:

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
      -[DeezerReachability connectionRequired] in libDeezer.a(DeezerReachability.o)
      -[DeezerReachability currentReachabilityStatus] in libDeezer.a(DeezerReachability.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress", referenced from:
      +[DeezerReachability reachabilityWithAddress:] in libDeezer.a(DeezerReachability.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
      +[DeezerReachability reachabilityWithHostName:] in libDeezer.a(DeezerReachability.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[DeezerReachability startNotifier] in libDeezer.a(DeezerReachability.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[DeezerReachability stopNotifier] in libDeezer.a(DeezerReachability.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
      -[DeezerReachability startNotifier] in libDeezer.a(DeezerReachability.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

__*_*_SOLVED!
the problem wasn't in the deezer api but in a missing link with a library. I've had to add the system framework in 'link with libraries' in the 'project build phase'.

Comment: If you're using XCode 5, did you try removing armv7s from "valid architectures" and put "build active architecture" to "no"?

Comment: yes I've tried this solution. but the deezer player gives problem with the armv7

Comment: as for the example project, i've now switched the standard arch 32, and set to NO for valid arc. but i still get errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the SystemConfiguration framework is needed. 
Can you mark your question as "Resolved".

Thanks.